# get records where one colum has values within range across records with same column names

Tags: sql, postgresql

with a table like below

```
+------+-----+------+----------+-----------+
| city | day | hour | car_name | car_count |
+------+-----+------+----------+-----------+
|    1 |  12 |   00 | corolla  |         8 |
|    1 |  12 |   00 | city     |         9 |
|    1 |  12 |   00 | amaze    |         3 |
|    1 |  13 |   00 | corolla  |        17 |
|    1 |  13 |   00 | city     |         2 |
|    1 |  13 |   00 | amaze    |         8 |
|    1 |  14 |   00 | corolla  |         3 |
|    1 |  14 |   00 | amaze    |         1 |
+------+-----+------+----------+-----------+
```

need to find out the `city, day, hour` where the `car_count` for all `car_name`s is >= 3 and <= 10

expected result

```
| city | day | hour |  
+------+-----+------+ 
|    1 |  12 |   00 |
```

Comment: What should happen, when a day (i.e. `14` in your example) doesn't have a row, which other days have (`car_name=city` in your example)? Should it be considered `car_count=0` (so that day should not be returned at all), or is it enough that the rows you *actually have* satisfy the given condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`.

```
select city,day,hour
from tablename
group by city,day,hour
having sum(case when car_count>=3 and car_count<=10 then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select city, day, hour
from t
group by 1, 2, 3
having bool_and(car_count >= 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **group by** on city, day and hour with the **having** condition **sum(your condition) = count(your condition)**
So basically we are creating a flag for each row which satisfies the condition "10 >= car_count >= 3" . Now we are summing all the flags and counting them simultaneously, if both the count and sum are equal that means your condition "10 >= car_count >= 3" was true for all the cars against city,day and hour

```
create table want as
select city,day,hour from have
group by city,day,hour
having sum(car_count>=3 and car_count<=10)=count(car_count>=3 and car_count<=10);
```

Please let me know in case of any queries.